# Set-ADUser Ignore Populated Attributes

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a script that I'm using to update AD attributes from a CSV. The script works fine, but I've been asked to **not** update user attributes that are already populated. For example, if the user phone number attribute is populated in AD, ignore this and move on to the next attribute. Can anyone help me understand the best way to accomplish this?

Here's my script as it exists now:

```
    $users = import-csv -path c:\temp\testing_user.csv -delimiter "$"
foreach ($user in $users) {            
 Get-ADUser -filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.userid)'" -Properties * -server ($user.Domain) 
 Set-ADUser -Identity $user.userid -OfficePhone $($user.Phone) -Title $($user.Title) -Manager $($user.mgruserid) -Department $($user.dept)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Set-ADUser` doesn't have a `-NoClobber`. So you'll need to test for each property. Probably most clear to have a separate `if` block for each property and set them individually.

```
$users = import-csv -path c:\temp\testing_user.csv -delimiter "$"
foreach ($user in $users) {            
    $ADUserObject = Get-ADUser -filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.userid)'" -Properties * -server ($user.Domain)
    if ($null -eq $ADUserObject.OfficePhone) {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $user.userid -OfficePhone $($user.Phone)
    }
    ...
}
```